# Regarding rails testing with Capybara &Rspec ...capybara element not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models in my rails app let say company model and lead model to add leads. I have to test lead form while adding new lead. so I used integration testing . I have fields on my form through which i updated the db too but capybara errors element not found.my code as folows

new lead form

```
<title>Add Contact</title>
<h1> Enter Lead information</h1>
<%= form_for @lead, :url => lead_path(@lead.id), :html => { :multipart =>true } do|f|%>                                                                                      
<p>
<%= f.label :Name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :Linkedln_Address, 'Linkedln_Address' %><br>
<%= f.text_field :linkedln_address %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :Twitter_Feed, 'Twitter_Feed'%><br>
<%= f.text_field :twitter_feed %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :avatar, "Image File" %>
<%= f.file_field :avatar %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :Notes, 'Notes' %><br>
<%= f.text_area :notes %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>'`
```

my spec is
spec/requests/leads_spec.rb

```
`require 'spec_helper'
 describe "POST /lead", type: :feature do
  it 'creates and saves valid lead' do
      visit "/lead/new" 
     fill_in 'Name', :with => "abcdefg"
        fill_in 'linkedln_address', with: 'lmnop@gmail.com'
    fill_in 'twitter_feed', with: 'www.twiitter.com/microsoft'
     fill_in 'notes', with: 'ajkhd akjf \n alskdfh alsjdfh'
     click_button 'create Lead'


    current_path.should ==lead_path
    page.should have_content 'The Lead is Successfully Added'
    within 'h1' do
     page.should have_content "abcdefg"
    end
    page.should have_content "lmnop@gmail.com"
     page.should have_content "www.twiitter.com/microsoft"
      page.should have_content "ajkhd akjf \n alskdfh alsjdfh"
  end
    end
```

`

Comment: Do you know which element Capybara is having trouble locating? What's the actual error being raised?

Answer (score 0):

Capybara is case sensitive, your button is probably 'Create Lead' and not 'create Lead' (should also verify other fields)